# Eclipse rcp view remove icon

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

My requirement is to remove the title icons for all views but it seems impossible.

First i removed the references to the icons from extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views" in my plugin.xml file.

There is a similar question to this one where it is suggested to override getTitleImage() in the view that extends ViewPart so i did just that and i tryed 2 versions.

```
@Override
public Image getTitleImage() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Image getTitleImage() {
    return new Image(getSite().getShell().getDisplay(), new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));
}
```

The result no matter which method i used is that some views don't display the icon and some do. For example the first view is always opened without the icon but the following views get the default icon. Also if i have save and restore enabled and restart the application while leaving some views open, the one that is selected doesn't have the icon while the rest do.

This is so frustrating, i just don't get why something so simple has to be so complicated to implement.

Comment: It should be possible. Please see this plogpost http://www.richclient2.de/2007_04_16/customizing-the-ui-in-small-rcp-projects/ Note, that there is also an archive with source code available for download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is views that have not yet been created (so `getTitleImage` has not been called). In that case the workbench part reference code uses the default image if there is nothing defined in the view definition.

If the above is correct creating an empty image icon file and defining that as the icon in the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension in your `plugin.xml` should work.

Comment: Thats right, the problem was that getTitleImage() was not called. So the soulution was to add a transparent image of 1 pixel width to org.eclipse.ui.views while also overriding getTitleImage(). Also had some problems with eclipse not using the empty image, but it was solved by clearing the workspace.